# Why cannot we use @Inject inside a static block

Tags: java, spring, static

I referred through lots of links and blogs , but could not get a perfect answer to this question . 
I can use

```
static {
    Test test = new Test();
}
```

but not

```
static {
@Inject 
Test test; 
}
```

Why is this so?

Comment: The duplicate question is about `@Autowired` but the same applies to `@Inject`.

Comment: @Thomas: Except that this question is about a *local* variable!

Comment: @ruakh yes, you're right. Local variables can't be injected anyways.

Comment: Somehow I couldnt find that question in stack overflow. It answers my query perfectly! Thanks all.